# Does someone have matlab on a mac with the compiler toolbox

Tags: matlab, compilation

I have developed some matlab code which uses the sparse field method to segment images (active contours). It includes:

The geodesic implementation  (casselles)
Gradient Vector Flow (N Pokalinous )
Region Aided Snake ( X Xie)
Magenostatic Snake (X Xie)
Local Active Contours with kernel selection (D Boukouri)
Local Active Contours with kernel selection (wang et al)
Traditional Global (Chan and Vese)
Local with Edges (D Boukouri)
Local with VVector Forces 
Generalised Vector Forces (Prince)

To make it useful I need it to be compiled on a mac using the mcr. I don't have a mac - can some one help me or suggest a work around?

Cheers

D

Comment: Bulder JA available? If so it is much easier to deploy platform independent code to a jar file instead.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I was not aware this existed